# Highlighting a .diff file

Tags: verbatim, highlighting

Is there a way to highlight the syntax of a diff file (i.e. by using the `listings` package)?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can just do this with the `listings` package, and you won't even need an external pre-processor. `listings` doesn't come with a diff style but you can define one like this:

```
\lstdefinelanguage{diff}{
  morecomment=[f][\color{blue}]{@@},     % group identifier
  morecomment=[f][\color{red}]-,         % deleted lines 
  morecomment=[f][\color{green}]+,       % added lines
  morecomment=[f][\color{magenta}]{---}, % Diff header lines (must appear after +,-)
  morecomment=[f][\color{magenta}]{+++},
}
```

Use it in the usual ways. E.g., `\lstinputlisting[language=diff]{myfile.diff}`.

**Update:** Diff viewers often highlight the background of lines, instead of coloring the text. This can be added with the help of Martin Scharrer's `lstlinebgrd` package, available on CTAN in his [`lstaddons`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lstaddons) bundle (or get the latest version from [the package homepage](https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/lstaddons))

Comment: Indeed, diff syntax is pretty simple! Thanks for having replied even with an accepted answer…

Comment: Welcome. If you figure out how to set the *background* color for any of these, please demonstrate. I'm not sure `listings` can set the background of anything smaller than a whole listing.

Comment: (Update: I found out about `lstlinebgrd`, which can set the background color).

Answer (score 13):

[minted](http://code.google.com/p/minted/)?

```
\begin{minted}{diff}
<diff data goes here>
\end{minted}
```

would work, or

```
\inputminted{diff}{path/to/file.diff}
```

if you want to just read the diff from a file.
Minted also provides a [listing](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/blob/master/source/minted.pdf) command you can use to wrap it in a floating box like a figure or table.

Comment: Indeed, `pygmentize -L lexers` shows that `diff` is supported.

Comment: @egreg: I know, I checked it on the project's web page first;).

Comment: Great! I don't have the time to change all my other listings to minted though (I use lstlistings). Is there a way to use lstlistings settings for minted?

Comment: (And I couldn't resist having a go at the lowest-answer-length-to-upvotes-ratio contest:P.)

Comment: @mbork The comment was intended as a spur to improve the answer. ;-)

Comment: @mbork remove the ? then!

Comment: @GaretJax: lol.  But joking aside: I have no experience with any of these packages.  But I guess that it *might* be not too difficult to do the transition, either by changing the source file through regexps or by making a macro wrapper for `minted` with `listings` syntax (probably more difficult).  Could you put an MWE of what you want to achieve (e.g., your settings) into your question?  Then someone might help you (not me, probably;)).

Comment: @egreg: as I wrote above, I have no experience in syntax highlighting in LaTeX...

Comment: Don't worry… I'll use keep my (single) diff file unhighlighted for this time and will be using minted from now on. I didn't even knew it existed ;)

Answer (score 6):

I extended the answer from alexis to cover more formats: normal format (`diff`), unified format (`diff -u`), context format (`diff -c`) and diffs from Git (`git diff`):

```
\lstdefinelanguage{diff}{
  sensitive=true,
  % diff command line
  morecomment=[f][\color{gray}][0]{diff},
  % commit identifiers for git diff
  morecomment=[f][\color{gray}][0]{index},
  % hunk location/line numbers for unified format
  morecomment=[f][\color{blue}][0]{@@},
  % hunk location/line numbers for context format
  morecomment=[f][\color{magenta}][0]{***},
  % changed line for context format
  morecomment=[f][\color{violet}][0]{!},
  % deleted lines for unified format
  morecomment=[f][\color{red!60!black}][0]-,
  % added lines for unified format
  morecomment=[f][\color{green!60!black}][0]+,
  % file name and time stamp old file
  morecomment=[f][\color{magenta}][0]{---},
  % file name and time stamp new file
  morecomment=[f][\color{magenta}][0]{+++},
  % Binary files ... differ
  morecomment=[f][\color{gray}][0]{Binary},
  % Only in ...: file.txt
  morecomment=[f][\color{gray}][0]{Only},
  % old mode ...
  morecomment=[f][\color{gray}][0]{old},
  % new mode ...
  morecomment=[f][\color{gray}][0]{new},
  % rename from/to ...
  morecomment=[f][\color{gray}][0]{rename},
  % similarity index ...%
  morecomment=[f][\color{gray}][0]{similarity},
  % deleted file mode ...%
  morecomment=[f][\color{gray}][0]{deleted},
  % hunk separator for context format
  morecomment=[f][\color{magenta}][0]{***************},
  % deleted lines for normal format
  morecomment=[f][\color{red!60!black}][0]<,
  % added lines for normal format
  morecomment=[f][\color{green!60!black}][0]>,
  % line number specifier for normal format
  morecomment=[f][\color{blue}][0]{0},
  % line number specifier for normal format
  morecomment=[f][\color{blue}][0]{1},
  % line number specifier for normal format
  morecomment=[f][\color{blue}][0]{2},
  % line number specifier for normal format
  morecomment=[f][\color{blue}][0]{3},
  % line number specifier for normal format
  morecomment=[f][\color{blue}][0]{4},
  % line number specifier for normal format
  morecomment=[f][\color{blue}][0]{5},
  % line number specifier for normal format
  morecomment=[f][\color{blue}][0]{6},
  % line number specifier for normal format
  morecomment=[f][\color{blue}][0]{7},
  % line number specifier for normal format
  morecomment=[f][\color{blue}][0]{8},
  % line number specifier for normal format
  morecomment=[f][\color{blue}][0]{9},
}[comments]
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) And thanks for your first contribution! :-)