# Is there a ready solution to typeset a diff file?

Tags: formatting, environments

In a text about Git I want to typeset diffs similar to this visualization:
[Commit details on GitHub](https://github.com/openlilylib/openlilylib/commit/534e4dbb90fc23e94cfea3f4949cb15f49d90fd7).

[image]

Is there any ready-made solution to that, especially the coloring of the diff lines?
(In other commits there may be even an additional highlighting of the actual changed part of a line with a different background color.

Of course I could 'roll my own' but don't want to reinvent the wheel.

(Searching for `LaTeX` and `diff` only seems to mathematical symbols or how to diff LaTeX documents ...)

Comment: You could use `minted`, potentially with a custom style for Pygments?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can also use `listings`. You must define an own language with own colour settings. The lines with special characters are defined as comment lines here:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
  \definecolor{diffstart}{named}{Grey}
  \definecolor{diffincl}{named}{Green}
  \definecolor{diffrem}{named}{OrangeRed}

\usepackage{listings}
  \lstdefinelanguage{diff}{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    morecomment=[f][\color{diffstart}]{@@},
    morecomment=[f][\color{diffincl}]{+\ },
    morecomment=[f][\color{diffrem}]{-\ },
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=diff]
@@ -85,8 +85,8 @@
\newcommand{\doctitleifsub}[2]{%
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{center}
-    \sffamily This document is part of the documentation of \openlilylib%
-    \footnote{\url{https://github.com/openlilylib/openLilyLib}},\\
+    \sffamily This document is part of \textbf{\openlilylib}%
+    \footnote{\url{http://www.openlilylib.org}},\\
    a collection of resources for the LilyPond notation software%
    \footnote{\url{http://www.lilypond.org}}\\
    and the \LaTeX{} typesetting system.
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Comment: Thanks for this. I like the idea of taking the plus and minus as 'comment indicators'.

Comment: Some apps create patch files that don't have a space after the +/- signs, if you copy & paste the above solution but it doesn't work, try removing the "\ " (slash-space) from the end of the second and third lines that start with "morecomment="

Answer (score 23):

Using the `verbatim` package you can easily apply formatting to each line, so this just extracts the first character and uses it as part of a colour name to use for the highlighting.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim,color}
\makeatletter

\long\def\diffcolor#1#2\@nil{color\string#1diff}

\def\verbatim@processline{%
\nointerlineskip\noindent\rlap{%
\colorbox{\expandafter\diffcolor\next..\@nil}{%
\the\verbatim@line}}\par}
\makeatother

\definecolor{color diff}{rgb}{1,1,1}
\definecolor{color-diff}{rgb}{1,.5,.5}
\definecolor{color+diff}{rgb}{.5,1,.5}

\begin{document}



\verbatiminput{diffex.diff}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @MarcoDaniel shouldn't that +1 have been in green:-)

Comment: Changed my accepted answer because the `listings` approach doesn't affect _all_ environments but can be applied only when applicable.

Comment: @uli_1973 I'll survive the loss of 15 :-) You could of course just locally define `\verbatim@processline` for the environments that need it, but there is no harm (and some sense) in using an accepted package interface if it supports this.

Comment: Is it possible to adapt the solution to minted package? (I really like minted style, but I got no clue how to highlight part of the code like the diff sections)

Answer (score 14):

The [vim](https://github.com/adityam/filter/blob/master/vim-README.md) module for ConTeXt uses the VIM editor to do the syntax highlighting of files. As such it supports all syntax highlighting for all filetypes supported by VIM (which is a lot). For example, to highlight diff files, you may use:

```
\usemodule[vim]

\definevimtyping[DIFFtyping][syntax=diff]

\starttext
\startDIFFtyping
@@ -85,8 +85,8 @@
 \newcommand{\doctitleifsub}[2]{%
   \thispagestyle{empty}
   \begin{center}
-    \sffamily This document is part of the documentation of \openlilylib%
-    \footnote{\url{https://github.com/openlilylib/openLilyLib}},\\
+    \sffamily This document is part of \textbf{\openlilylib}%
+    \footnote{\url{http://www.openlilylib.org}},\\
     a collection of resources for the LilyPond notation software%
     \footnote{\url{http://www.lilypond.org}}\\
     and the \LaTeX{} typesetting system. 
\stopDIFFtyping
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

*Full disclosure*: I am author of the vim module.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `verbments`, provided you have Pygmentize on your machine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbments}
\begin{document}
\begin{pyglist}[language=diff]
@@ -85,8 +85,8 @@
 \newcommand{\doctitleifsub}[2]{%
   \thispagestyle{empty}
   \begin{center}
-    \sffamily This document is part of the documentation of \openlilylib%
-    \footnote{\url{https://github.com/openlilylib/openLilyLib}},\\
+    \sffamily This document is part of \textbf{\openlilylib}%
+    \footnote{\url{http://www.openlilylib.org}},\\
     a collection of resources for the LilyPond notation software%
     \footnote{\url{http://www.lilypond.org}}\\
     and the \LaTeX{} typesetting system.
\end{pyglist}
\end{document}
```

Running LaTeX with `-shell-escape` enabled is required.

[image]

Comment: How is verbments different from minted?

Comment: @Aditya See [minted vs texments vs verbments](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102596/minted-vs-texments-vs-verbments)

Answer (score 6):

I took a combination of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50263/18668) answer and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/267786/18668) answer to get a `listings` environment closer to the git diff visualizations, with coloured line backgrounds rather than coloured text.

[image: output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\lstbg}[3][0pt]{{\fboxsep#1\colorbox{#2}{\strut #3}}}
\lstdefinelanguage{diff}{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
  morecomment=[f][\lstbg{red!20}]-,
  morecomment=[f][\lstbg{green!20}]+,
  morecomment=[f][\textit]{@@},
  %morecomment=[f][\textit]{---},
  %morecomment=[f][\textit]{+++},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=diff]
@@ -85,8 +85,8 @@
\newcommand{\doctitleifsub}[2]{%
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{center}
-    \sffamily This document is part of the documentation of \openlilylib%
-    \footnote{\url{https://github.com/openlilylib/openLilyLib}},\
+    \sffamily This document is part of \textbf{\openlilylib}%
+    \footnote{\url{http://www.openlilylib.org}},\
     a collection of resources for the LilyPond notation software%
     \footnote{\url{http://www.lilypond.org}}\
     and the \LaTeX{} typesetting system.
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```