# Colored background in listings environnement

Tags: listings, color

I would like to make my `listings` environnements more readable by coloring the background of some keywords with a specific color. Like this :

[image]

I thought using the `\colorbox` function from `xcolor` package but It only work with an argument (not as `\color`) and doesn't work with listings.

**Is there another way to get colored text background working with `listings` environnement?**

Comment: Are you specifically referring to *inline* listings?

Comment: this is surely possible since `listings` allows for setting keywordstyles and also has a mechanism for escaping to LaTeX. However, it is rather unclear to me how you want to use it. (E.g., the picture you posted doesn't look at at like a listing!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to use `keywordstyle`, `identifierstyle` etc. and set them to a specific colour or use a specific colour background with `\colorbox{colorname}` -- The relevant 2nd argument to `\colorbox` will be inserted by `listings` automatically. Please note, that this might look not as well as desired, see the example in the C - language with the descenders of the `#` - symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{listings}


\begin{document}

\lstset{ keywordstyle={\colorbox{yellow}},identifierstyle={\colorbox{green}}}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C]
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  printf("Hello World\n");
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Adding to [Christian's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/267730/70587), you might want to fix height of `colorbox`es and set their padding to zero, so that they don't change layout of your code.

[image: print screen of result]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\myColorBox}[3][0pt]{{\fboxsep#1\colorbox{#2}{\strut #3}}}

\begin{document}

\lstset{columns=fullflexible,basicstyle=\ttfamily,keepspaces,language=C}

\begin{lstlisting}
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  printf("Hello World\n");
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[
  keywordstyle={\myColorBox{yellow}},
  identifierstyle={\myColorBox{green}}
]
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  printf("Hello World\n");
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```