# How to put source code in a LaTeX table?

Tags: tables, listings, sourcecode

I am  comparing  source in a paper and I would like to put them in a table, so the differences are easily spotted. I used the following LaTeX code:

```
\begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l |}
Option 1  &  Option  2 & Option 3 \\
\begin{lstlisting}
Code A
\end{lstlisting} &
\begin{lstlisting}
Code B
\end{lstlisting} &
\begin{lstlisting}
Code C
\end{lstlisting} \\
\end{tabular}
```

When compiled, this becomes a mess, so that is why I would like to know what I can do to improve the outcome.

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX. Your code snippet, when inserted in a minimal document, does not produce any mess. Can you expand your code to a complete, compilable example (starting with `\documentclass`, ending with `\end{document}`) that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: If your snippets are one-liners, I would also consider `\lstinline`.  Also, instead of a tabular, have you considered `multicol`?

Comment: It's not the format you'd specifically asked for, but it may be worth using if you can live with comparing two blocks of code: `diff` and [Is there a ready solution to typeset a diff file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105995/is-there-a-ready-solution-to-typeset-a-diff-file/106129#106129) or [Highlighting a .diff file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50176/highlighting-a-diff-file)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In addition to what said by David in his answer, you need to set `breaklines=true` otherwise the whole thing can become a mess if you have long lines.

For example, the following MWE (with that option set)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  language=C,
  basicstyle=\small,
  breaklines=true
  }

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|p{3.6cm}|p{3.6cm}|p{3.6cm}|}
Option 1  &  Option  2 & Option 3 \\
\begin{lstlisting}
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("Hello world\n");
}
\end{lstlisting}&
\begin{lstlisting}
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("Hello world\n");
}
\end{lstlisting}&
\begin{lstlisting}
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("Hello world\n");
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{tabular} 

\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

while, without that option, the output is

[image]

Answer (score 5):

`l` is a single line cell set to its natural width. You want each cell to be a parbox so use
`p{5cm}` or some other suitable length, then the cell can contain display material such as a listing.