How to show side-by-side Programming code?
Hi I am using Overleaf for a paper and I am trying to present programming code before my optimizations and after my optimizations (highlighting lines that go away in red and new optimized lines in green) to show the differences to the reader?
Is there any package to do this that is doable without installing lots of externals that you can't do on Overleaf? I can still use packages though.
Example:
before:
int main() {
  int a = 4;
  int b = 2;
  int sum1 = a + b;
  int sum2 = a + b;
  int prod1 = sum1 * sum2;
  sum1 = 0;
  sum2 = 0;
  int sum3 = a + b;
  int prod2 = sum3 * sum3;
  return prod2;
}

after:
int main() {
  int a = 4;
  int b = 2;
  int lvn0 = a + b;
  int lvn1 = lvn0 * lvn0;
  return lvn1;
}

In markdown i can use the + and - at the start of the line to do this easily but how do i do this in latex?

please provide a complete example showing what you've tried. or at least provide code for a document which typesets the two blocks one after another as a baseline.

Are you familiar with the listings package and its lstlisting environment, or the fancyvrb package and its Verbatim and Verbatiim* environments?

Note: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58540/highlight-lines-in-listings is not exactly the same, but a good starting point. Extending the answers to use two instead of only one color should be easy. If not, please show what you've tried.

Create a diff file from the two versions of your code and then you can use https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50176/highlighting-a-diff-file

I disagree on the closing vote reasons: though the duplicates mentioned tackle the highlighting issue, they don't put results side-by-side as requested, as far as I've seen.

@MS-SPO If using two minipages would really be a problem, I would close the question because it should be more focused … ;-)
